# Laravel how to compare dates in controller

Tags: php, laravel, date, controller

I'm trying to compare dates to get the next events doing a attach and detach, this is my code:

**In Controller:**

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {   
        $actualDate =  date('Y-m-d');
        $event_id = $request->route('id');
        $event = Event::find($event_id);
        $event_date = $event->event_date;
        
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        if ($user->events($event_id)->count() == 1 && $user->events($event_date) >= $actualDate){
            $user->events()->attach($event_id);
            return redirect('/');
        }else if($user->events($event_id)->count() != 0){
            $user->events()->detach($event_id);
            return redirect('/home');
        }
    }
```

Comment: did an error occur? What do you expect?

Comment: `$user->events($event_date)` most likely won't work because `events()` is a relationship. You can't pass a date into it. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @aynber. It should be `$event_date >= $actualDate`

Comment: I want to compare the date of the event I'm getting to the actual date to make an attach, because if its a past event I cannot attach it, for the project of course.

Comment: Okay, ignore the `$user->events($event_date)`, then. You can use Laravel's [casters to cast `event_date` as a date](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting), which will then allow you to use [Carbon functions](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), such as [isPast()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

in the model try this to access it as a date property, or you can use an accessor.

```
 protected $dates = ['event_date'];
```

then in the function.

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {   
        $actualDate =  Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', '12/01/2020 11:20:00');
        $event_id = $request->route('id');
        $event = Event::find($event_id);
        $event_date = $event->event_date;
        
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        if ($user->events($event_id)->count() == 1 && $user->events($event_date)->gte($actualDate)){
            $user->events()->attach($event_id);
            return redirect('/');
        }else if($user->events($event_id)->count() != 0){
            $user->events()->detach($event_id);
            return redirect('/home');
        }
    }
```